# Yet another interchange of limit and sum (revised)

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

A revised version of a similar [question I asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036596/yet-another-interchange-of-limit-and-integral).

$S_n$ are finite sets containing rational numbers in [0,1] for which $S_n\subset S_{n+1}$ and $\lim_n S_n = \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$.

$f_n:S_n\to\mathbb{R}$ are uniformly-bounded functions that converge to a continuous function $f$, that is $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in S_n$.

Is it true that

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{|S_n|} \sum_{x\in S_n} f_n(x) = \int_0^1 f(x)\, \mbox{d}x
$$

Comment: Hint: What happens for $f_n = f$ for all $n$?

Comment: @PhoemueX if $f_n=f$ what we get is a Riemann integral so it should be ok. So I may guess there must be a positive answer to my question?

Comment: @guest, if $f_n=f\equiv1$, then the limit is infinite but the RHS is one. You should introduce some normalization to your limit of sums over growing finite sets to keep it finite.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta yes my goodness, of course I forgot the normalization. I made the edit,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the points in $S_n$ are not chosen uniformly enough, it may well happen that your limit is the integral of $f$ against a nonconstant weight function. The claim is false even for $f_n=f$ if you don't make more assumptions. Consider for example the sets
$$
S_n=\{0,\frac1{4n},\frac2{4n},\dots,\frac{2n-1}{4n},\frac12,\frac{n+1}{2n},\frac{n+2}{2n},\dots,\frac{2n-1}{2n},1\}.
$$
The two thirds of the points are uniformly distributed on $[0,\frac12]$ and one third on $[\frac12,1]$. Thus the limit for a Riemann integrable $f$ is
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{|S_n|} \sum_{x\in S_n} f(x)
=
\frac23\int_0^{1/2} f(x)\, \mbox{d}x
+
\frac13\int_{1/2}^1 f(x)\, \mbox{d}x.
$$
Keep in mind that in the Riemann sums you also need the lengths of the intervals. If they are not uniform, an unweighted sum does not approximate the integral.

Comment: Thanks. So at least I could realize in advance that I need at least the same assumptions required by the Riemann integral... beyond those, I wonder whether the uniform boundedness and the pointwise convergence of the $f_n$'s are enough